# Strategy Pattern too many if statements

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture

A user enters a code and the type of that code is determined by regular expressions. There are many different type of codes, such as EAN, ISBN, ISSN and so on. After the type is detected, a custom query has to be created for the code. I thought it might be a good idea to create a strategy for type, but with time it feels wrong.

```
public interface SearchQueryStrategie {

    SearchQuery createSearchQuery(String code);
}
```

-

```
public class IssnSearchQueryStrategie implements SearchQueryStrategie {

    @Override
    public SearchQuery createSearchQuery(final String code) {
        // Create search query for issn number
    }
}
```

-

```
public class IsbnSearchQueryStrategie implements SearchQueryStrategie {

    @Override
    public SearchQuery createSearchQuery(final String code) {
        // Create search query for ISBN number
    }
}
```

-

```
public class EanShortNumberSearchQueryStrategie implements SearchQueryStrategie {

    @Override
    public SearchQuery createSearchQuery(final String code) {
        // Create search query for ean short number
    }
}
```

-

```
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final String code = "1144875X";

        SearchQueryStrategie searchQueryStrategie = null;
        if (isIssn(code)) {
            searchQueryStrategie = new IssnSearchQueryStrategie();
        } else if (isIsbn(code)) {
            searchQueryStrategie = new IsbnSearchQueryStrategie();
        } else if (isEan(code)) {
            searchQueryStrategie = new EanShortNumberSearchQueryStrategie();
        }

        if (searchQueryStrategie != null) {
            performSearch(searchQueryStrategie.createSearchQuery(code));
        }
    }

    private SearchResult performSearch(final SearchQuery searchQuery) {
        // perform search
    }

    // ...
}
```

I have to say that there are many more strategies. How should I dispatch the code to the right strategy?
My second approach was to put a boolean method into every strategy to decide if the code is correct for that strategy.

```
public class TestApplication {

    final SearchQueryStrategie[] searchQueryStrategies = {new IssnSearchQueryStrategie(), new IsbnSearchQueryStrategie(),
            new EanShortNumberSearchQueryStrategie()};

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        final String code = "1144875X";

        for (final SearchQueryStrategie searchQueryStrategie : searchQueryStrategie) {
            if (searchQueryStrategie.isRightCode(code)) {
                searchQueryStrategie.createSearchQuery(code);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private SearchResult performSearch(final SearchQuery searchQuery) {
        // perform search
    }

    // ...
}
```

**How would you solve this problem? Is the strategy pattern the right one for my purposes?**

Comment: You need to implement the `isRightCode` method of the interface

Comment: Strategy is fine, and you really cannot get rid of branching. At the very end you'll still end up with if/else or switch (in either explicit or implicit form), so you have two ways: keep it more simple and declare the `isRightCode` method of the strategy interface as @cricket_007 is suggesting you in order to iterate over a collection of strategies (some kind of a repository), or you can follow a more complicated way to use factories that would accept a code and return a strategy from the factory. Both of them can work, but I would go with the first one.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Java 8 and you can profit from the functional features I think one Enum will be sufficient.

You can avoid using if/else statements by mapping each type of code with a Function that will return the query that needs to be executed:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public enum CodeType
{
    EAN("1|2|3"),
    ISBN("4|5|6"),
    ISSN("7|8|9");

    String regex;
    Pattern pattern;
    CodeType(String regex)
    {
        this.regex = regex;
        this.pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    }

    private static Map<CodeType, Function<String, String>> QUERIES =
            new HashMap<>();
    static 
    {
        QUERIES.put(EAN, (String code) ->  String.format("Select %s from EAN", code));
        QUERIES.put(ISBN, (String code) -> String.format("Select %s from ISBB", code));
        QUERIES.put(ISSN, (String code) -> String.format("Select %s from ISSN", code));
    }

    private static CodeType evalType(String code)
    {
        for(CodeType codeType : CodeType.values())
        {
            if (codeType.pattern.matcher(code).matches())
                return codeType;
        }
        // TODO DON'T FORGET ABOUT THIS NULL HERE
        return null;
    }

    public static String getSelect(String code)
    {
        Function<String, String> function = QUERIES.get(evalType(code));
        return function.apply(code);
    }
}
```

And in the main you can test your query:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        System.out.println(CodeType.getSelect("1"));
        // System.out: Select 1 from EAN
        System.out.println(CodeType.getSelect("4"));
        // System.out: Select 4 from ISBB
        System.out.println(CodeType.getSelect("9"));
        // System.out: Select 9 from ISSN
    }
}
```

I usually tend to keep the code as compact as possible.

Some people dislike enums, so I believe you can use a normal class instead.

You can engineer further the way you obtain the QUERIES (selects), so instead of having String templates you can have a Runnable there.

If you don't want to use the the functional aspects of Java 8 you can use Strategy objects that are associated with each type of code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public enum CodeType2
{
    EAN("1|2|3", new StrategyEAN()),
    ISBN("4|5|6", new StrategyISBN()),
    ISSN("7|8|9", new StrategyISSN());

    String regex;
    Pattern pattern;
    Strategy strategy;

    CodeType2(String regex, Strategy strategy)
    {
        this.regex = regex;
        this.pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    private static CodeType2 evalType(String code)
    {
        for(CodeType2 codeType2 : CodeType2.values())
        {
            if (codeType2.pattern.matcher(code).matches())
                return codeType2;
        }
        // TODO DON'T FORGET ABOUT THIS NULL HERE
        return null;
    }

    public static void doQuery(String code)
    {
        evalType(code).strategy.doQuery(code);
    }
}

interface Strategy { void doQuery(String code); }
class StrategyEAN implements Strategy {
    @Override
    public void doQuery(String code)
    {
        System.out.println("EAN-" + code);
    }
}
class StrategyISBN implements Strategy
{

    @Override
    public void doQuery(String code)
    {
        System.out.println("ISBN-" + code);
    }
}
class StrategyISSN implements Strategy
{

    @Override
    public void doQuery(String code)
    {
        System.out.println("ISSN-" + code);
    }
}
```

And the main method will look like this:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        CodeType2.doQuery("1");
        CodeType2.doQuery("4");
        CodeType2.doQuery("9");
    }
}
```

Comment: For short code, I would definitely prefer your answer using enums to full-blown factories or service locators.

Comment: @tucuxi I believe it really depends on the type of application. Anyway, in the Java World people tend to oversaturate the code with patterns, even when they are not quite needed.

Comment: Definitely functional way is nicer. That was a really good asnwer !

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not the Strategy Pattern. Strategy Pattern is all about customizing behavior of an object (`Context` in terms of this pattern) by passing alternative `Strategy` object to it. By this way, we don't need to modify the source code of the `Context` class but still can customize the behavior of objects instanced from it.

Your problem is somewhat related to the Chain of Responsibility (CoR) Pattern where you have a request (your `code`) and need to figure out which `SearchQueryStrategie` in a predefined list should handle the request.

The second approach -- using array -- that you mentioned is fine. However, to make it usable in production code, you must have another object -- let's say `Manager` -- that manages the array and is responsible to find the relevant element for each request. So your client code have to depend on two objects: the `Manager` and the result `SearchQueryStrategie`. As you can see, the source code of `Manager` class tend to be changed frequently because new implementations of `SearchQueryStrategie` may come. This might make your client annoyed.

That's why the CoR Pattern uses the linked list mechanism instead of array. Each `SearchQueryStrategie` object A would hold a reference to a next `SearchQueryStrategie` B. If A cannot handle the request, it will delegate to B (it can even decorate the request before delegating). Of course, somewhere still must know all kinds of strategies and create a linked list of `SearchQueryStrategie`, but your client will then depend only on a `SearchQueryStrategie` object (the head one of the list).

Here is the code example:

```
class SearchQueryConsumer {
    public void consume(SearchQuery sq) {
        // ...
    }
}

abstract class SearchQueryHandler {
    protected SearchQueryHandler next = null;
    public void setNext(SearchQueryHandler next) { this.next = next; }
    public abstract void handle(String code, SearchQueryConsumer consumer); 
}

class IssnSearchQueryHandler extends SearchQueryHandler {
    @Override
    public void handle(String code, SearchQueryConsumer consumer) {
        if (issn(code)) {
            consumer.consume(/* create a SearchQuery */);
        } else if (next != null) {
            next.handle(code, consumer);
        }
    }

    private boolean issn(String code) { ... }
}
```

Comment: I am really not convinced by this linked-list-of-delegated-responsibility. I would much prefer a for-loop iterating over the list to having the strategies delegate to each other.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said that using array and iterating over it is just fine, as long as the client is happy to depend to a `Manager` object, and the request is not required to be decorated before delegating. But I don't understand how can "the strategies delegate to each other" when they don't know -- link to -- each other?

Answer (score 1):

So, The strategy pattern is indeed the right choice here, but `strategy` by itself is not enough. You have several options:

1. Use a `Factory` with simple if/else or switch. It's ugly, error prone to extend with new strategies, but is simple and quick to implement.
2. Use a registry. During the application initialization phase you can register in  a `registry` each SearchQueryStratgeyFactory with the right code. For instance if you use a simple `Map` you can just do :

   `strategyRegistry.put("isbn", new IsbnSearchStrategyFactory());
   strategyRegistry.put("ean", new EanSearchStrategyFactory());
   .... and so on`

   Then when you need to get the right strategy you just `get()` the strategy factory from the map using the code id. This approach is better if you have a lot of strategies, but it requires an aditional iitialization step during the application startup.
3. Use a service locator. ServiceLocator is a pattern that enables the dynamic lookup of implementations.  Java comes with an implementation of the ServiceLocator pattern -> the infamous `ServiceLoader` class. This is my favourite approach because it allows for complete decoupling of the consumer and implementation. Also using the service locator you can easily add new strategies without having to modify the existing code. I won't explain how to use the ServiceLoader - there is plenty of information online. I'll just mention that using the service locator you'll need to implement a "can process such codes ?" logic in each strategy factory. For instance if the factory cannot create a strategy for "isbn" then return null and try with the next factory.

Also note  that in all cases you work with factories that produce the strategy implementations.

PS: It's `strategy` not `strategie` :)

Answer (score 0):

What i recommend is using the `Factory` pattern. It describes and handles your scenario better.

[Factory Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm)

Comment: The factory requires the use of the if-else statements, though, which the point of the question was to remove

Comment: @cricket_007 A delegating factory can use a service locator or some form of a registry to delegate to another factory to create the object. No ifs, no conditionals - just pure OOP

Answer (score 0):

You can design in the following way (using concepts of factory DP and polymorphism):

1. `Code` as interface.
2. `ISSNCode`, `ISBNCode` and `EANCode` as concrete classes
   implementing `Code` interface, having single-arg constructor taking text as String.
3. `Code` has method `getInstanceOfCodeType(String text)` which returns an instance of a sub-class of `Code` (decided by checking the type of `text` passed to it). Let's say the returned value be `code`
4. Class `SearchQueryStrategieFactory` with
   `getSearchQueryStrategie(code)` method. It consumes the returned value from step 3, and generates different
   instances of `SearchQueryStrategie` *subclasses* based on `code` type using `new` operator and, then returns the same.

So, you need to call two methods `getInstanceOfCodeType(text)` and `getSearchQueryStrategie(code)` from anywhere.

Instead of ***implicitly*** implementing the factory inside main, keep the whole *factory* code separate, to make it **easily maintainable and extensible** .

Comment: if `Code` is an interface, then point 2 (which requires having a static method in an interface) is suspect. You probably want to change point 2 to "have a `CodeFactory` class that contains a single static method called `getInstanceFor()`"